# ngOnInit is not triggered while navigating/routing back to component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngoninit

I want to retrieve and assign data from a service to component to view and update. It worked but whenever I navigate to other route and come back it disappeared and everything is undefined. I need a solution for this case.

TodoComponent

```
ngOnInit(){
      this.abv = this.memberData.memberData$.subscribe(res => {
        this.todos = res.todos.todo;
        this.done = res.todos.done;
      })
    }
```

Routing-Module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component:MemberComponent, children:[
    {path:'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
    {path:'todo', component: TodoComponent}
  ]}
];
```

Service

```
    this.memberData$ = this.memberRef.snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
        map(action => {
            const data = action.payload.data();
            const id = action.payload.id;
            return { id, ...data };
        })
     );
```

Comment: Can you add more details ? it happen when you navigate from  ProfileComponent to TotoComponent ?  The ngOnInit is in the member component ? and you navigate from  'profile' to 'todo' ?

Comment: ngOnInit is in todo component. I'm trying to assign todos from a service. But when I navigate to profile component and back to todo component it disappears.
Member(parent) having two childs => profile(child), todos(child)

Comment: Can you add your `memberDate` service?

Comment: When you said that ngOnInit is not called you mean not are not going into the subscribe callback or you are not doing in the ngOnInit at all ?

Comment: use `OnDestroy` to unsubscribe `this.abv`

Comment: I've done unsubscribing on destroy too!

Comment: When I tried refreshing the page. It's working as expected but coming back after navigation it changes everything to null